# This has to do with writing and reading binary files

Tags: java, binaryfiles

This is the steps im supposed to go through. I tried writing the files but i think its wrong.

1. Creates 10 binary files in a folder called “binaryfiles”. The files must be named “temp0.dat”, “temp1.dat”, etc. to “temp9.dat”.
2. In each file, write 20 random doubles between 0 and 500. Inclusivity doesn’t matter.
3. Once the files are written, open each one in sequence from “temp0.dat” to “temp9.dat” and read them one character at a time. As you read the files, print the characters to the output window. Most of the characters will look like Chinese characters.

public class Homework7 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("binaryfiles");
    file.listFiles();
    System.out.println("We have a file" + file);

    System.out.println("Does it exist" + file.exists());
    System.out.println("?" + file.isDirectory());
    Random random = new Random(20);
    random.setSeed(500);
    double num = random.nextDouble();
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outStream.write((int) num);
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a fit for this type of questions. You have to code yourself and in case of having problems, you can come back here, show us your code, and tell us where you fail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework forum. If people on here feel like they are doing your homework for you, they're not going to help. Show what kind of effort you have put in yourself, what steps you have already taken. Specify what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: Read the Java IO tutorial. Use a DataOutputStream to write double, and use FileReader to read. Be aware that your teacher is explicitely asking you to do something stupid, that you should never do in a correct program. The javadoc and the tutorial should allow you writing this code on your own.

Comment: Im sorry guys, i didnt ask to do the homework for me. I asked to help me explain how to write a binary file so i can do the homework. The only reason i put the steps up here is to show you that i have to write the file first before doing any other thing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

All files are binary at the lowest level (we talk about different types of files because we choose to interpret the bytes as something else on a higher level) and you create one using an `OutputStream` and then you write to it either using the stream directly or by using something that writes to the stream for you.

I'm not going to solve this for you since it sounds like a learning assignment, so instead I suggest you look closer at [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).